# How to do a call through a javax.xml.ws.Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, java-7

Created a new standard java 7 project in Eclipse and have successfully managed to get an instance of a `javax.xml.ws.Service` like so:

```
  String wsdlURL = "http://example.com:3000/v1_0/foo/bar/SomeService?wsdl";
  String namespace = "http://foo.bar.com/webservice";
  String serviceName = "SomeService";
  QName serviceQN = new QName(namespace, serviceName);

  Service service = Service.create(new URL(wsdlURL), serviceQN);
```

This runs fine in a main method, so as far as I can see, that part works. But I can't figure out how to actually use it. In SoapUI I call this same service with a request which looks like the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://foo.bar.com/webservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:SomeWebServiceRequest acAccountName="name" acAccountPassword="password">
         <SomeRequest>
            <id>012345678901234</id>
            <action>Fix</action>
         </SomeRequest>
      </web:SomeWebServiceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I do the same request in Java? My goal is that I have a long list of these `id`s, and I need to run a request like that for each of them. Doing it manually in SoapUI is a bit annoying, so I'd like to automate it with a simple Java console application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Next step is to get `Port` from your service:

```
Service service = Service.create(new URL(wsdlURL), serviceQN); // this is where you are.
QName portQName = new QName(portNamespace, portName);
YourPortInterface port = service.getPort(portQName, YourPortInterface.class);
```

`YourPortInteface` will be generated during `wsimport` or you can create and annotate it by yourself if you have enough experience in "reading" wsdl.

Comment: Is the `QName` for the port different from the service? And this `YourPortInterface`, is that just a simple class with annotations? Could you give a simple example?

Comment: @Svish, `QName` is different, you can see port name when opening wsdl in a browser (`portType` node). As for example, I could do it of course, but that'd be useless for you without entire wsdl. Much better idea would be runinnig `wsimport http://any.public.service/service?wsld`, and see the results comparing them to wsdl in a browser. `wsimport` or `wsimport.exe` is a binary file in your JRE.

Comment: ah, ok. Cool, will try that out then :)

Comment: can "port" be used as a singleton?. without needing to do getPort on each call to the service?

Comment: in java9 it doesn't work if you use a local WSDL, when using a custom runtime generated with jlink

Answer (score 2):

You can use JAX-WS as a client.

Basically you use wsimport to create stub java classes which wrap the web service, then you use those stubs in your java code.
The stubs take care of all the XML translation, both for your request and response.

The tutorial is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html
Look for the part called: "A Simple JAX-WS Client"