# Creation of Object for Service class is not working

Tags: java, javascript, xml, jsp, servlets

public CI[] getCIDetailsTest(String ci_type,String selectedCI) throws Exception{

```
        String endpoint = getProperty(customerID+"_endpoint");
        System.out.println("reached here .......done.."+endpoint);
        //here failed 
        Service service = new Service();
        System.out.println("reached here .......done..........."+service);
```

That is my statements in Java file

But, to my surprise it was unable to create Service Object..

It is printing first println statement and not printing second println statement. That means It was unable to creat Service object.

Is it jar problem? If it is jar problem, Which jar to be included?

Friends, Kindly Help me out to resolve this issue....

Comment: Service class is interface/abstract class ?

Comment: public class Service
extends java.lang.Object
Service objects provide the client view of a Web service.

Comment: can you paste complete class Service and what exactly problem you facing ?

Comment: System.out.println("reached here .......done.."+endpoint);
        //here failed 
        Service service = new Service();
        System.out.println("reached here .......done..........."+service);

Comment: That is my code.. it is printing "reached here .......done.." but it is not printing second "reached here .......done......"

Comment: I am not shakti man that without see any code can find the issue.Please paste the code.

Comment: @ANILBABU, you should use the edit button to add your details pls

Comment: what you wanted to do with this service class.?if i'm not wrong you might have confused between service method and service class.?isn't it

Comment: Possible Duplicate :- <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922655/how-to-do-a-call-through-a-javax-xml-ws-service>

Answer (score 0):

you should add this jar:

1. **math3-commons-3.2.jar**
2. **XStream-1.4.4.jar**
3. **jaxws-api-2.2.5.jar**

The problem is the version of `JAX-WS API`. The classloader for your application first loaded the version included in Java SE or Java EE.

For `Java SE 6 or Java EE 5, JAX-WS API 2.1.` The constructors in [***javax.xml.ws.Service***](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html):

```
javax.xml.ws.Service.Service(URL, QName)
```

For Java `SE 7 or Java EE 6, JAX-WS API 2.2.` The constructors in [***javax.xml.ws.Service***](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html):

```
javax.xml.ws.Service.Service(URL, QName)
javax.xml.ws.Service.Service(URL, QName, WebServiceFeature...)  // You need this!
```

There are three possible solutions (depends on whether it is a web application or standalone application):

1. Use `Java SE 7 or Java EE 6`.
2. Re-run wsdl2java with argument -frontend `jaxws21` to generate
   `JAX-WS 2.1` compliant code instead.
3. Change the classloader for load first the classes included in the
   application.

you should refer this [***link***](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/05/axis.html)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the Service is (a not) abstract class and not an interface. 
It must also have a public constructor.

Comment: Sorry, the constructor is protected and not visible for you. But there are static methods to create an Instanzen for you. Means this class follows the factory Pattern. Use x = Service.create(...);