# How to use javax.xml.ws without interface of soap webService

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to use a SOAP webservice with below URL:

http://ws.armaghan.net:8080/ws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl

According to post at [How to do a call through a javax.xml.ws.Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922655/how-to-do-a-call-through-a-javax-xml-ws-service) I developed below code:

```
URL url= new URL("http://ws.armaghan.net:8080/ws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl");


QName qname= new QName("http://webservice.smsrelay.armaghan.net/","MessageRelayService");


Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
```

but at next step I do not now how to use `service.getPort(Claas arg0)` because I have not the interface of my SOAP web service. The only thing I have is the above URL.

By the way my question is that how can I use the web-service?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a tool for generating the interfaces and the client. I usually save the wsdl file to my java project and use the ide to generate source code from the wsdl file.

Then you can choose your preferred framework. Axis, cxf, ws or what you want.

You can also use commandline tools like for example this

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Comment: Very thanks @AnAmuser . the tools give me two kind of files. one .java and one .class.Do I should add both of them in my project?

Comment: You can add the java files which are generated sourcecode to your project. When you compile your project they will be compiled to the same class files.

Comment: @AnAmuser: should the same be used for unit tests for SOAP Webservice also or is there any other optimized way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to generate the client for the Web service through **WSIMPORT** or similar tool.

after that the generated client artifacts should be integrated with your client side code to call web service operations. you can refer following blog post that has the clear steps one by one.

http://chathurangat.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-generate-jax-ws-client-and.html